# During a git merge, if I "Discard Changes" why is the file deleted?

Tags: git, git-merge

I was merging a colleague's branch with the `master` branch in our project repo. When I `fetched` his changes and attempted to `merge` them into the master branch, I had a few conflicts, so I ran `git mergetool` to resolve them.

Once I got done with the `merge`, I was looking at the changes in the GitHub GUI app. All of the files that were merged from my colleague's branch are marked as "New", even though they're not new files at all. If I right-click on any of the files and click "Discard Changes", it deletes the file from the repository if I commit the `merge`. I'm sure there is a logical explanation. Why are the files deleted if I "Discard Changes"? Why are files marked as "New" during a merge even if they've been there for a long time?

Comment: Where are you clicking "discard changes"?

Comment: @LoïcFaure-Lacroix I am clicking "discard changes" in the GitHub GUI app, after I right-click on a file.

Comment: If you can click discard changes, it means that thoses changes we're not added to the commit when you pushed. For example, you merged the files and all but it didn't add the changes to the commit. You pushed and the changes (merged file) remained locally

Comment: Also if you're not familiar with all this and CLI, I suggest this link: http://pcottle.github.io/learnGitBranching/ Honestly GUI usually suck and if you understand how git works, this can help you fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it's the problem you're having but it sounds like it. Git doesn't track files but its content. For example, If you move a file. Using `git status` you'll see that a file has been deleted and there is a new untracked file.

If you add both changes to the commit, git will check their content and assume that the file as been renamed. Which is good. You can even copy a file and add it and it will mark it as a copy because the content is the same. Each file will point internally to the same `Object`. Which means that copies or moved files will inherit history.

Now let say that, during a commit, you deleted a file commited and added it back during the merge. (This might be what's happening with the discard changes). Git will see that the file has been deleted and then a new file has been created. Since the file wasn't present in the previous commit, it will mark it as new which is totally right.

On other possible reason is that the new file has 100% changes. I can't say for sure but if it happens. I wouldn't be surprised if git might think that the file as been replaced by a new file.

On a side note, I'd suggest doing a `git blame` on of the files marked as new. This will give you changes on the file with the name. If on each lines, there is only one person and one date. This could mean that the file is really new and github isn't falsely marking the file as new. If there are changes, then something is wrong with github.

## Edit

If it's not to late, I'd consider to redo the merge. If nothing new has been pushed to the merged tree, it won't be a terrible thing to fix. When doing the merge, make sure that all changes are added to the changeset. During a merge, conflicted file will not be added to the staging area. I can't say that mergetool will automatically add merged files to the staging. In any case do a `git add {file}`, on all these files. If the file was already present, it will not change anything. Once you're sure that everything is right. Push it. You might have an error that you're trying to push non-fastforward commit that will overwrite commits. If it doesn't work try with "git push -f". And it should work.